# apache is redirecting all to SSL but still getting non-ssl log

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I've just moved to ssl on apache, so i added this directive to my default conf

```
 Redirect 301 / https://the-checkout-tech.com/
```

with a log file called access.log

Added a new ssl conf file with all the right ssl bits
and a log file called access.ssl.log

but I find half the traffic is ending up in access.log and the other half in access.ssl.log

Should I be combining the conf files? or should I be sending both conf files to the same access.log or am I doing something silly? (When browsing, all requests end up being https, so I havn't split the site between http and https)

Regards

Comment: Well, what kind of hits do you get in access.log ? It still needs to handle the initial Redirect, and if all your visitors only visit each page once, then yes, half the requests would end up in the non-ssl one

Comment: Okay so even redirect to http to https will still log in the non-ssl log?

Comment: Yes, the redirect request is handled by the plain HTTP port

Comment: ah, so no prob just merging the two logs in to one?